# Rewrite domain to another domain's subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have this page --

`www.example.com/landing-page`

But I would like to use a different domain for it, i.e. `www.example2.com`

I'm using cPanel on a Linux machine (LAMP), could this be done via `.htaccess`?

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: is the www.example2.com is registered for u??

Comment: Yes I have control over it and the DNS etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via apache's VirtualHosts, open your apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file
and apply something like this inside it:

```
VirtualHostName example2.com:80
<VirtualHost example2.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/htdocs/landing-page"
    ServerName example2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

JAVASCRIPT REDIRECT:

Paste this at the top of your page on the old site just after the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.newsite.com/"
</script>
```

Naturally, you'd replace "http://www.newsite.com/" with wherever you wanted the page to redirect to.

It should redirect you instantly. So anyone visiting the old site page will instantly redirect to newsite.com

PHP REDIRECT (301, permanently moved):

```
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.newsite.com/" ); 
?>
```

Place that at the top of your page. It isn't as nice as the javascript one, but it is SEO FRIENDLY, which I think you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but no - I want example.com/landing-page to still be there, but when people go to example2.com it acts as though it is the exact same page as the the other one but with a different domain.